# timezone support in django

Tags: django, timezone

I'm trying to get the various US timezones supported in Django. I'm able to get the `America/New_York`, etc. But my question is for places like Hawaii? I'm not able to find the proper timezone setting for it? Is there a place for all the available settings that we can use in Django? I want to build an application and give the user the ability to choose the timezone they are in.. Thanks for the help!

Comment: The full list of timezones denoted by `TZ*` is here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name. PyTZ has all of those timezones built in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See "[What you need to know about date/time](http://pyvideo.org/video/946/what-you-need-to-know-about-datetimes)" (nice video from PyCon 2012).

```
>>> import pytz
>>> pytz.all_timezones
['Africa/Abidjan',
'Africa/Accra',
'Africa/Addis_Ababa'
...
'US/Pacific-New',
'US/Samoa',
'UTC',
'Universal',
'W-SU',
'WET',
'Zulu']
```

Data available:

```
all_timezones = ['Africa/Abidjan', 'Africa/Accra', ...]
all_timezones_set = set(['Africa/Abidjan', 'Africa/Accra', ...]
common_timezones = ['Africa/Abidjan', 'Africa/Accra', ...]
common_timezones_set = set(['Africa/Abidjan', 'Africa/Accra', ...])
country_names = {u'BD': u'Bangladesh', u'BE': u'Belgium', ...}
country_timezones = {u'BD': [u'Asia/Dhaka'], u'BE': [u'Europe/Brussels'] ...}
```

Comment: Nice, I had no idea I could get all timezones like that

Comment: @kalvish: see the updates, posted a link for a nice video from PyCon2012.

Comment: The thing I find discouraging is, if we want to make an internationally available application, how can we possibly know every available timezone in teh world? Is there a more easy way to figure out?

Comment: @kalvish: date/time can be even trickier than finding the correct timezone. Day Light Savings, leap seconds and all the mess.

Comment: Dont get you? I'm only dealing with US timezones, so I have EST, MST, CST, PST, Alaska, Arkansas, and Hawaii? I took cities in each of those regions?

Comment: @kalvish: if you want to simplify things for the user, you can try to guess the TZ using javascript to get the current client timezone. Then put the choices that have the same offset first.